# Extjs 4.1 file upload programmatically in some events

Tags: file-upload, customization, extjs4.1

I want to upload a file using Extjs 4.1 file upload control. I have fileupload field in my form which will be hidden from users. but i have a image. if user double clicks to that image browse file dialog should be shown as in "Browse..." button of Fileupload control. Please help me...

Comment: Where are your efforts? Show your code please.

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean exactly like in the Sencha examples? 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/file-upload.html

[image]

**EDIT**: Use [buttonOnly:true](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-buttonOnly) config option to hide the fileinput field and leave only the upload button visible.

Comment: Thanks for reply DmitryB I know about file-upload of extjs but in my case user will not click browse button of file-upload filed, he/she will click image control to upload a file. Is it possible?

Comment: r u serious? There is a link in my answer with an example of a custom image right next to the fileinput just like you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but its not my requirement. the example is just for how to set button icon. My problem is say.. I have file upload filed as shown in above image. the file upload filed will be invisible to user including browse button. And i have another button or image control(which is not related to file upload filed) in which user will click to upload file. Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you want to hide the file field you can use buttonOnly:true config . Please read the documentation - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-buttonOnly

Comment: Actually my requirement is explained in image. Please see the image i cant attach image here... [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/34es3s4.png)

Comment: fake it. make your image the icon class for the upload button and hide the input.

Comment: Thats ok if there is only one image but i have lots of thumbnail image in a page which is not possible...

Comment: I don't know how you are going to implement this. You need to let users select file first and then upload it to the server through a form submit. A set of hidden inputs might work... use case seems wacky though.